# Kali on vmware, intel 7260 wont appear

Tags: wireless-networking, vmware-player

I downloaded the latest kali virtual drive, after downloading and installing the latest kali on my actual computer with about the same issues, the wireless card was acknowledged, but otherwise unuseable. ethernet however on vm does appear to work which was good.

I then updated the virtual drive, still nothing, here are some informations with which im hoping someone can identify the problem

driver: intel AC 7260
currently bridging, but

**lspci**

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 [AudioPCI-97] (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller`

**lsmod**

`Module                  Size  Used by
nfnetlink_log          17241  0 
nfnetlink              13040  1 nfnetlink_log
binfmt_misc            16942  1 
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    30059  0 
vsock                  30772  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
fuse                   87579  3 
vmhgfs                 51885  0 
loop                   26605  0 
dm_crypt               22731  0 
joydev                 17108  0 
btusb                  30039  0 
bluetooth             391914  2 btusb
vmwgfx                178693  1 
ttm                    77757  1 vmwgfx
drm_kms_helper         81088  1 vmwgfx
drm                   259436  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,vmwgfx
i2c_piix4              20864  0 
psmouse               103371  0 
snd_ens1371            23119  2 
snd_rawmidi            26856  1 snd_ens1371
snd_seq_device         13132  1 snd_rawmidi
snd_ac97_codec        118710  1 snd_ens1371
snd_pcm                88786  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1371
snd_timer              26606  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69333  10 snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_ens1371,snd_seq_device
soundcore              13026  1 snd
shpchp                 35217  0 
vmw_vmci               55778  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmw_balloon            12658  0 
i2c_core               50145  3 drm,i2c_piix4,drm_kms_helper
ac97_bus               12510  1 snd_ac97_codec
serio_raw              12849  0 
gameport               17589  1 snd_ens1371
evdev                  17489  5 
rfkill                 18902  2 bluetooth
irda                  109446  0 
parport_pc             26287  0 
coretemp               12820  0 
battery                13356  0 
crc_ccitt              12347  1 irda
processor              28221  0 
parport                35699  1 parport_pc
8250_fintek            12787  0 
thermal_sys            32286  1 processor
ac                     12715  0 
button                 12988  0 
ext4                  490614  1 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82464  1 ext4
dm_mod                 93340  1 dm_crypt
vmw_pvscsi             21447  0 
vmxnet3                48262  0 
sr_mod                 21903  0 
cdrom                  47424  1 sr_mod
sg                     29919  0 
ata_generic            12490  0 
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 48599  0 
hid                   102292  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sd_mod                 43575  3 
crct10dif_pclmul       13348  0 
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    12978  0 
aesni_intel           167997  0 
aes_x86_64             16719  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    12757  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               12970  1 lrw
glue_helper            12690  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            12572  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 18656  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
e1000                 122792  0 
ata_piix               33592  0 
uhci_hcd               43524  0 
ehci_pci               12512  0 
ehci_hcd               69703  1 ehci_pci
usbcore               199549  5 btusb,uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid
usb_common             12561  1 usbcore
mptspi                 21943  2 
scsi_transport_spi     27849  1 mptspi
mptscsih               26718  1 mptspi
libata                177633  2 ata_generic,ata_piix
mptbase                72947  2 mptspi,mptscsih
floppy                 65147  0 
scsi_mod              199895  8 sg,scsi_transport_spi,libata,mptspi,vmw_pvscsi,sd_mod,sr_mod,mptscsih`

**modinfo iwlwifi**

`filename:       /lib/modules/3.18.0-kali3-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     F3691B048EBD3B518243A23
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.18.0-kali3-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)`

**dmesg | grep intel**

`[    0.172184] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'cpu cycles' unavailable
[    0.172185] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'instructions' unavailable
[    0.172186] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'bus cycles' unavailable
[    0.172186] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'cache references' unavailable
[    0.172187] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'cache misses' unavailable
[    0.172187] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'branch instructions' unavailable
[    0.172188] perf_event_intel: CPUID marked event: 'branch misses' unavailable
[    1.888529] intel_idle: does not run on family 6 model 60
[    1.936617] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel 440BX Chipset
[    1.939157] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0x0
[    3.791517] platform microcode: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel-ucode/06-3c-03
[    3.791536] platform microcode: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel-ucode/06-3c-03
[    3.791550] platform microcode: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel-ucode/06-3c-03
[    3.791564] platform microcode: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel-ucode/06-3c-03
[   16.255271] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[   16.276633] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[   16.501011] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[   16.533721] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0`

**aptitude show firmware-iwlwifi**

`Package: firmware-iwlwifi

State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 0.44~kali1
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/kernel
Maintainer: Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 16.4 M
Suggests: initramfs-tools
Description: Binary firmware for Intel Wireless cards
 This package contains the binary firmware for Intel Wireless cards supported by
 the iwlegacy/iwl3945 and iwlwifi/iwlagn drivers. 
 Contents: 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 Bluetooth firmware patch
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 rev 10 Bluetooth firmware patch
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 rev 10 WP2 B5 Bluetooth firmware path
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 rev 10 Bluetooth firmware patch
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 Bluetooth firmware generic patch (intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq)
 * Intel Wireless 7265 rev 10 Bluetooth firmware generic patch
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265 Bluetooth firmware generic patch
   (intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265 Bluetooth firmware generic patch (intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq)
 * Intel Wireless 100 firmware, version 39.31.5.1 (iwlwifi-100-5.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 105 firmware, version 18.168.6.1 (iwlwifi-105-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 135 firmware, version 18.168.6.1 (iwlwifi-135-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 1000 firmware, version 39.31.5.1 (iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 2200 firmware, version 18.168.6.1 (iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 2230 firmware, version 18.168.6.1 (iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 firmware, version 22.1.7.0 (iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 firmware, version 22.24.8.0 (iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 firmware, version 25.228.9.0 (iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 3160 firmware, version 23.11.10.0 (iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 3945 firmware, version 15.32.2.9 (iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 4965 firmware, version 228.61.2.24 (iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 5100, 5300 and 5350 firmware, version 8.24.2.12
   (iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 5100, 5300 and 5350 firmware, version 8.83.5.1
   (iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 5150 firmware, version 8.24.2.2 (iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6000 firmware, version 9.221.4.1 (iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6005/6205 firmware, version 17.168.5.3
   (iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6005/6205 firmware, version 18.168.6.1
   (iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6030 firmware, version 18.168.6.1 (iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6250 firmware, version 9.201.4.1 (iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 6250 firmware, version 41.28.5.1 (iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 firmware, version 22.1.7.0 (iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 firmware, version 22.24.8.0 (iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 firmware, version 25.228.9.0 (iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7260 firmware, version 23.11.10.0 (iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265 firmware, version 22.24.8.0 (iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265 firmware, version 25.228.9.0 (iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265 firmware, version 23.11.10.0 (iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode) 
 * Intel Wireless 7265D firmware, version 23.11.10.0 (iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode)
Homepage: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
Tags: admin::hardware, implemented-in::c, role::app-data, role::data,
      role::program, use::driver`

**ifconfig -a**

`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:82:0f:44

          inet addr:192.168.10.26  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe82:f44/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:215147 (210.1 KiB)  TX bytes:44682 (43.6 KiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2160 (2.1 KiB)  TX bytes:2160 (2.1 KiB)`

im quite new so im not sure if i missed anything, also i removed some of the results due to the vmware

Also, my computer im using is toshiba qosmio x70, running windows 8.1

besides displaying the card name of the 7260 on kali partition installed, the outcome is the same, though on vmware i have internet via the network bridge.

Please help ive been looking all over i dont know what to do.

Comment: so its impossible to run the standard wifi tools then on a kali image?

still i have about the same problem anyway on the hard drive installed linux, with the sole difference being that the wifi adaptor can be seen as connected to the computer, but thats it, just a name that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting your wireless card to appear in the virtual machine?  It doesn't work that way.  VMware virtual machines don't "see" any of your real hardware except the CPU; everything else is virtual hardware emulated by VMware itself.

The network bridging feature works sort of like an internal (wired) Ethernet switch that the host's wireless card and the VM are both plugged into.  Packets sent by the VM through its virtual Ethernet card are repeated through the host's wireless card, but the VM doesn't have any direct control over the wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's impossible to "see" hardware on a VM, but only that connected to the motherboard. You can always get a USB wireless adapter and play with Kali

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: @DavidPostill is proposing to get a USB device not contributing something new? I don't see "USB device" anywhere else in this page. It may not be the brightest reply, but the final intention of the question is to get a wireless card working on Kali.